# Non Clickable Navigation Menus

Tags: navigation, menu, hyperlinks

[image]

I am building a website in wordpress. My website navigation have few main menu's and 2 main menus have their submenu's. Each main menus and sub menus redirecting to their corresponding pages except for the **Product** menu in the diagram.

Below are my question.

- The user will expect a page on the **Product** menu ?.
- If the user click on the Product menu, how can I indicate that there
  are no page linked with the same?.
- Is there any chance that a user might think there is an error in the navigation?.

Remember, I am using wordpress for building my website, wordpress generate menus dynamically and  put it only in the `<a>`, so it is not possible to change the style of the mouse pointer.

Comment: Why doesn't it have a page? It could link to a page with a general description of the products and why the company is making those, or when there are more than a few products a page which lists them all, possibly categorized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Users will expect "About" and "Product" to behave the same way. So however you treat one, treat them both.

If you can't do usability testing to see what actual people do on your site, at least pay attention to your own expectations and reactions as you browse the web. Me, I don't usually expect menu headers to be clickable or not, but I do appreciate when they are, and when they go someplace useful.

Comment: In eCommerce, people have been taught to also click on top-level navigation items. Anyhow, some go against this, which would speak for Ken's answer: amazon.com or asos.com even mix it up: Some headlines are clickable, some are not - which I think is not too useful. Asos at least differentiates the visual appearance of each (one is "inactive" grey, one is "active" black). Considering tablet/mobile (in)compatibility with "hover" states also might be worth a thought